# WebStorm Configure Inspections support for Jade

Tags: syntax-highlighting, pug, validation, webstorm

**Is there a way to add Jade support in [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)'s [Configure Inspections](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/inspections-2.html)?**

You can get to **Configure Inspections** by clicking on the *Yeoman lookalike* in the right below corner [image]

Jade plugin is active, but no Jade in **Configure Inspections**:

[image]

Which is annoying because when you have a jade template with invalid syntax (forgotten comma):

```
button(type='button' class='btn btn-primary')
```

WebStorm does not complain, but I get a nasty error when compiling the template. It would be easier to detect such errors faster.

Comment: The comma in between attributes is [optional in Jade as of Oct 1st 2013](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/662#issuecomment-25439958), so it actually **is** valid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jade plugin has no hidden features that have to be enabled in magical ways; the error highlighting you want is simply not implemented in the current version. You're welcome to file a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Answer (score 1):

Using the new "File Watchers" feature in the latest EAP it's possible to have WebStorm automatically compile Jade as you change the file. It will show errors in the output window as soon as they are detected.